# JQuery UI Draggable - Helper function which returns clone() only clones once if arguments passed to clone()

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, clone, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am cloning elements as they are dragged out of a JQuery UI Draggable list using JQuery's `clone()` method. Looking at the [`clone()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), I see that I can clone events already bound to these elements by passing one or two Boolean arguments `(true,true)` to the `clone()` method.

It's with passing these arguments that things get weird. If I just use `clone()` as shown below, things work as expected.

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: function(e) {
        return $(this).clone();
    }
});
```

In the above example I get unlimited clones, but my events tied to the cloned element are not cloned as well. So then, naturally, I want to add one or two arguments to this `clone()` method so that I can also clone events!

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: function(e) {
        return $(this).clone(true);
    }
});
```

But this makes things only clone once. See the below fiddles for examples!

Here's a fiddle with `clone(true)` which only clones once: 
http://jsfiddle.net/og937wy7/9/

And here's a fiddle with `clone()` which clones many times.
http://jsfiddle.net/og937wy7/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you misused `"clone"` in helper option - you can not specify a method as a string, string is just a identifier how jQueryUI handles dragging elements. You either give a method (callable), or a string, as [in the docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper).

If you set the helper option to `"clone"` instead of `"clone(true, true)"`, a dragged element will be copied (when "dragged"), and as I see in the fiddle, the events are also attached to it (since you bind events properly).

Try this in your fiddle:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone"
});
```

Comment: thanks for the post. I had actually realized that passing a function as a string was messing things up... but I've run into another peculiar problem. For some reason when i use clone() without arguments, things work well. When i try to add arguments for copying event handlers, it only clones once. Any idea why?

Comment: Please update your question with specifics and examples, so that I could take a look and try to figure it out.

Comment: Done. Updated question and both fiddles. The only difference to the two fiddles is the argument `true` addressed in the question.

Comment: And why again using `clone()`, which works, is not suitable for you? Your second fiddle works. Please explain more "verbosely" what is it you are asking..

Comment: Well you're right. I just removed the `True` argument and all my events still work properly because I'm binding them to the workspace vs the element itself. I must have been binding events differently when I first implemented this. Thanks for helping me find this out!!

Answer (score 1):

If i get your point, you'd like to make the element clone multiple times. Just removing the arguments from clone(true, true) will do the trick:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: function(e) {
        return $(this).clone();
    }
});
```

Comment: the arguments from the clone method are necessary for my use case as i need it to copy the events tied to them as well.