# JQuery draggable droppable clone events on dragged object

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am successfully dragging objects but these objects after they are cloned into new area do not preserve mouse events that were attached to them before they were dragged and dropped.

```
instance.find('.gt-playlist-content').find("div[class*=gt_draggable]:not(.ui-draggable)").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".gt_sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            var _item = jQuery(ui.helper); 

        }
    });


jQuery("#main .gt-playlist-content").droppable({
        tolerance: "touch",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
           //console.log(jQuery(ui.draggable));

       }
    });
```

Is there a way to clone events like you would do with jQuery?

```
$(elem).clone(true);
```

edit:

actually I found my answer here how to clone a helper [jquery-ui-draggable-helper-function-for-clonetrue-true-only-clones-once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108687/jquery-ui-draggable-helper-function-for-clonetrue-true-only-clones-once)

although this clone plugin instance data which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class the dragging elements. And,

```
$('body').on('click','.theClass',function(){

    //Your codes
});
```

this click event would work for dynamically added elements.

Comment: No, this is not acceptable, its not just click, item should be cloned with data and events.